# Parsec negative match

Tags: haskell, parsec

```
parseIdent :: Parser (String)
parseIdent = do
  x <- lookAhead $ try $ many1 (choice [alphaNum])
  void $ optional endOfLine <|> eof
  case x of
    "macro" -> fail "illegal"
    _ -> pure x
```

I'm trying to parse an alphanumeric string that only succeeds if it does not match a predetermined value (`macro` in this case).

---

However the following is giving me an error of:

```
*** Exception: Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Prim.many: combinator 'many' is applied to a parser that accepts an empty string.
```

Which does not make sense, how does `many1 (choice [alphaNum])` accept an empty string?

---

This error goes away if i remove the `lookAhead $ try`. But it 'fails' with `illegal`:

```
...
*** Exception: (line 6, column 36):
unexpected " "
expecting letter or digit or new-line
illegal
```

---

Am I going about this correctly? Or is there another technique to implement a negative search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost have it:

```
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.Char
import Text.Parsec.String
import Control.Monad

parseIdent :: Parser (String)
parseIdent = try $ do
  x <- many1 alphaNum
  void $ optional endOfLine <|> eof
  case x of
    "macro" -> fail "illegal"
    _ -> pure x
```

So, why didn't your code work?

- the `try` is in the wrong spot. The real backtracking piece here is backtracking after you've gotten back your alphanumeric word *and* checked it isn't `"macro"`
- `lookAhead` has no business here. If you end up with the word you wanted, you *do* want the word to be consumed from the input. `try` already takes care of resetting your input stream to its previous state

Comment: This seems to work for a string like `abc` however it does not seem to work  in a specific context relating to `choice` and parsing for `macro`, and having an input such as `macabc`... Hmm perhaps better suited for a new question though. 

The error is:
```
unexpected "a"
expecting "macro"
```

Comment: Nevermind it just seems like 'choice` does not backtrace. Thanks for the explanation!